# How to detect incoming calls in background, in an Android app?

Tags: javascript, java, android, xml, call

**I'm trying to make an app like, when a call comes to the phone I want to detect calls in background** but  only able to detect calls when app is open or in recent apps . I tried many ways but not able to detect when app is completely closed ,   i want to detect calls like true-caller , Caller Name Announcer apps

Comment: this would help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlzfcqDlovg

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: zaid khan , already watchded but not working bro

Answer (score 0):

could use android foreground-services to do this. start your call listen service when the phone is boot.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services